# Generating Random Salt and IV - Must be Stored in Encrypted Data?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I'm trying to create some classes that wrap and simply the use of the .NET cryptography library classes.

But if I have the caller supply only a password, and I generate the salt and IV automatically, it seems like I then need to store the salt and IV along with my encrypted data. (This is because I am told I should never use duplicate IVs and my code wouldn't be very simple if the caller had to generate and track different salts and IVs.)

Ideally, my encrypted data would be as compact as possible. But this adds quite a few bytes to my encrypted results, especially if I'm only encrypting a small amount of data such as a single byte.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to reduce the size of my encrypted data without making my classes considerably more work to use?
2. Can anyone see any other flaws to my thinking here?

Comment: Does your system break when your encryption is not semantically secure? If not, then don't use random IVs and salts.

Comment: @ArtjomB.: Can you clarify what you mean by *semantically* secure? My understanding is that I should never use duplicate IVs and that it is not necessary to keep the IV secret. And I think things are similar for salts as well. So randomly generating these values seems like the only way to lift this burden from the caller.

Comment: Semantic security essentially means that the same plaintext encrypted with the same key/password will yield different ciphertexts which prevents attackers to get some meta-information about your plaintexts. This property directly follows from random salts and IVs. If this property is needed then you can't "compress" the ciphertexts further.

Comment: @ArtjomB.: Right, if I'm generating random salts and IVs, then different ciphertext for the same key/password. But the only alternatives I see to that is A) require the caller to create and track the salts and IVs, or B) always use the same salt and IV, which seems bad to me. Perhaps there is another option?

Comment: Yes, those are the two options you can choose from. I don't think we can choose for you. Note that you don't have to store both salt and IV, because you can derive the IV along with the key from password+salt.

Comment: @ArtjomB.: I am the one who will choose an option. I am trying to make sure I correctly understand all the options. That's why I asked if perhaps there is another option just above. But, yeah, only storing the salt is much better than storing the salt and IV. If the salt does not have to be secret, that's a big improvement.

Comment: Crypto almost always has some overhead.  Padding for example.  For any message of any size, just randomly make a salt, use it and the password with Rfc2898DeriveBytes to get the key and IV when you need them.  Prepend this salt unencrypted on the encrypted message.  Randomly use a new salt for each new message.  This salt can be 16 bytes, so if your message is a single typewritten page (2000 bytes) you increased the size of the ciphertext less than 1% but made it so even governments cannot guess a single bit of its contents (as far as we know).

Comment: @WDS: This is basically what I'm looking at. My concern with the overhead was not with a 2000 byte document, it was in the case when I had to encrypt a single byte. But perhaps that overhead is unavoidable. One thing: Doesn't the approach you just described use the same bytes for both the Key and IV? Isn't that a problem?

Comment: Yes, my approach does use the same bytes (the plaintext salt plus the shared password which is not in the transmission) for the IV and the Key.  As far as I know there is no security issue with this.  Rfc2898DeriveBytes will make random-looking (but completely deterministic) bytes for you so the same inputs yield the same outputs.  Like SHA-512 does, but Rfc2898DeriveBytes is made for the job.  Grab 32 bytes from Rfc2898DeriveBytes, 16 for the key and 16 for the IV, and you are good to go.

Comment: As for the very short messages, you could look into stream ciphers which eliminate the padding overhead.  They use a nonce (somewhat analogous to the IV) and a non-repeating counter to "scramble" the message more.  In those setups, the nonce needs be exchanged only once per session.  Check out CTR mode if this interests you.  Unfortunately it will still have a little overhead (no padding though), but depending on your circumstances, it may help reduce that overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a random salt and generate a key and IV from it. The best way to do this is first to generate a key seed using a Password Based Key Derivation Function or PBKDF. In the case of C# PBKDF2, as implemented in [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is probably the easiest choice. You'll need at least 8 bytes of salt and a high iteration count.

OK, so now you have a key seed, you need to generate a key from it. For this you need a Key Based Key Derivation Function or KBKDF. The most up to date one is HKDF (in which case you'd only need HKDF-extract to be precise). However KBKDF's are pretty uncommon in crypto libraries, so you it would take some time to implement it.

If you cannot find a good enough library then you may go for KDF1 [as specified on this page](http://www.di-mgt.com.au/cryptoKDFs.html). Just use the ASCII encoded string for "key" and "IV" as *OtherInfo* and set the counter to four bytes set to zero. The result is `key = Hash(key seed | 00 00 00 00 | "key")` and `IV = Hash(key seed | 00 00 00 00 | "IV")`. Here `|` means concatenation. If you have too many bytes, just use the *leftmost* ones from the result. SHA-1, SHA-256 and SHA-512 will do but I would recommend to use one that has enough output bits for your particular key - SHA-256 probably makes the most sense.

Once you have a key and IV you can use any kind of encryption method. For minimum overhead you can use CTR based encryption. Beware that if man-in-the-middle is possible (i.e. any transport protocol) then you *need to have an authentication tag as well*.

So there you have it: just 8 bytes of overhead, unless you need the authentication tag as well. What you should not do is to use a static key or IV. Neither a static key or IV is considered secure.

Comment: Thanks. A couple of questions: First, isn't `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` a valid way to generate a key? Second, I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean by *authentication tag*. I didn't quite understand the third paragraph. Am taking a look at the page you linked to.

Comment: An authentication tag is a value generated using a (H)MAC or authenticated cipher such as GCM. It adds integrity and authenticity to the ciphertext. Without it an attacker can not read the plaintext, but it is possible to alter it or even make up a ciphertext. Yes, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is enough to generate a key, but it is not a good idea to ask for more bytes than the underlying hash can provide. The default for PBKDF2 is SHA-1 giving only 160 bits; SHA-256 would give you 128 + 128 bits and SHA-512 gives you plent, but SHA-2 is not always availlable.